# Select all / Select none buttons not working on checkboxes

Tags: jquery, checkbox, selectall

I have searched for hours on this and read previous posts, but still no luck. In my code, individual countries tick and highlight nicely, but I can't get the select all/ untick all buttons to do anything.

My expected result is that: select all (`CountrySelectAll_ID_ws`) button should tick and highlight all 3 countries. The un-select button (`CountrySelectNone_ID_ws`) should remove all ticks and all highlights.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

I have a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/petg1bhb/

My code:

```
<input type="button" id="CountrySelectAll_ID_ws" value ='Tick all' />
<input type="button" id="CountrySelectNone_ID_ws" value ='UNtick' />

<div class="multiselect">
<br>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="1" />Germany</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="2" />France</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="7" />Spain</label>
</div>




jQuery.fn.multiselect = function() { 
$(this).each(function() {
    var checkboxes = $(this).find("input:checkbox");
    checkboxes.each(function() {
        var checkbox = $(this);
        // Highlight pre-selected checkboxes
        if (checkbox.attr("checked"))
            checkbox.parent().addClass("col-on");

        // Highlight checkboxes that the user selects
        checkbox.click(function() {
            if (checkbox.attr("checked"))
                checkbox.parent().addClass("col-on");
            else
                checkbox.parent().removeClass("col-on");
            alert$("option:selected");
        });
    });
});
};


$(function() {
 $(".multiselect").multiselect();
});


$(function() {
$("#CountrySelectAll_ID_ws").on('click', function()
$('.multiselect').find("input:checkbox").prop('checked',true);
})
});


$(function() {
$("#CountrySelectNone_ID_ws").on('click', function()
{
$('.multiselect').find("input:checkbox").prop('checked',false);
})
});
```

Comment: What's the expected result?

Comment: Select all button should tick and highlight all 3 countries.  Unselect should remove all ticks and all highlights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of ticking and un-ticking all the checkboxes in the div with the highlight formatting:

```js
$('#CountrySelectAll_ID_ws').on('click', function(e) {
  tickAll(true);
});
$('#CountrySelectNone_ID_ws').on('click', function(e) {
  tickAll(false);
});

// click on any checkbox
$('.multiselect input').on('click', function() {
  var input = $(this).parent();
  if (input.hasClass('col-on')) {
    input.removeClass('col-on');
  } else {
    input.addClass('col-on');
  }                           
});

// handle buttons                           
function tickAll(status) {
  $('.multiselect input').each(function(idx) {
    $(this).prop('checked', status)
    if(status) {
      $(this).parent().addClass('col-on');
    } else {
      $(this).parent().removeClass('col-on');
    }
  })
};
```

```css
.multiselect {
  width: 20em;
  height: 15em;
  border: solid 1px #c0c0c0;
  overflow: auto;
}
.multiselect label {
  display: block;
}
.col-on {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #000099;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="CountrySelectAll_ID_ws" value='Tick all' />
<input type="button" id="CountrySelectNone_ID_ws" value='UNtick' />

<div class="multiselect">
  <br>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="1" />Germany</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="2" />France</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="7" />Spain</label>
</div>
```

Comment: many thanks.  I didn't realise I was such a long way off!  However, Sellect All is not highlight the checkboxes.  Any ideas?

Comment: Wow, that's taken care of it, and much more efficient than my previous checkbox highlight code. You're a star!